# Going nuts with Exchange 2016 and the new Sectigo chain certificates

Tags: ssl, exchange

I've got a problem that I was wondering if anyone has run into before. I have Exchange 2016 running on Server 2012R2. I had a commercial certificate on it from namecheap.com this was a chained certificate through Comodo and then to USERTrust (I think) Everything was working fine and then, as usual, the certificate expired and needed to be renewed so I then renewed it through the process of letting the certificate expire then the day after it expired, going into the Exchange certificate wizard and running a new CSR then submitting the CSR to Namecheap and having them sign it and send me the certificate then applying that into the Exchange console wizard. No big deal I've done it a dozen times before.

Except for now. Exchange comes back with the error message "Revocation check failed" when the certificate is installed. Apparently Sectigo purchased Comodo a month or so ago and has started issuing certs that are tied to their OWN CA root (which is present in the latest OSes like windows 10, etc.) and crosssigning them with the old USERTrust root.

I have tried -everything- to make this error message go away:

1) deleted the CRL and OCSP caches with certutil

2) changed user with psexec to the system user and deleted the CRL and OCSP caches with certutil

3) Exported every root CA cert listing the name of Sectigo from a win10 system and imported them into the Server 2012R2 server - this only had the effect of changing the certificate verification path to the Sectigo root when viewing this in the certificate

4) Manually downloaded the 380 root CA certificates from Microsoft and installed them into the root certificate authority (on the plus side I can now do SSL with foreign websites that I don't speak the language of, ha ha. Did you know the Swiss government published a CA cert I didn't)

5) Re-issued the certificate (5 times, now)

6) Verified under the system account that IE is NOT using a "proxy" to get to the Internet (who puts a proxy on a mailserver???)

7) Verified all intermediate chained certificates exist in the Intermediate certificate store

8) Contacted namecheap support who insists the cert is perfectly fine.

Loading mmc with the cert snap in on the server shows all certificates in the chain with zero errors, all marked OK. The certificate is marked OK. I cannot find any diagnostic tool out there that thinks there's a problem in the certificate.

Finally in desperation I changed the services in Exchange to use the "Revocation check failed" certificate just to see what would happen - and everything works. There are zero error messages from any web browsers accessing OWA, no web browsers on any machines are complaining about revocation errors from this certificate, (not even the web browser ON the server) zero errors from a web browser run on the server itself accessing ECP, mail is flowing, the sun shines and cool breezes blow and the world is happy.

Except for that stupid Revocation error that STILL shows on the certificate in Exchange ECP.

Sectigo/Comodo appears to be THE go-to source for inexpensive SSL certificates on the Internet - virtually every "cheap SSL certificate site" on the Internet resells their stuff so all of these use this particular chain. They claim to have 50% of the SSL certs on the Internet and I believe them because you would have to be insane to fork over $200 a year for a godaddy or whatever certificate for a small business mailserver. In short I cannot find a CA that uses any other chain than that who is in the "inexpensive certificate market" Sectigo's M.O. appears to be to sell the expensive certs off their own website and cheap versions of the same certs out the back door to a plethora of small fry (like namecheap) who's support is horrible. I suppose that is to keep the RTFM questions tied up in the grass.

I have used their certificates on Sendmail servers, and webservers with no problems. But those don't do revocation checks when the certificate is installed. Only Exchange seems to do that.

I know I probably should just forget about it but it's BUGGING me. Everything was working before Comodo changed their name or got bought or whatever.

Comment: Have you checked if you can access the CRL or OCSP URLs from the server? The URLs the server needs to check to determine if the certificate is revoked is actually contained in the certificate. You can open the cert and view the info and test if you can access those URLs. See here for more info, although the test utility won’t help because it’s not a Digicert certificate: https://www.digicert.com/util/utility-test-ocsp-and-crl-access-from-a-server.htm additionally you can use fiddler to view the communication on the wire and determine what the server is doing and seeing as a response.

Comment: namecheap claims the new certs do not use the obsolete CRL urls but use only OCSP.  Namecheap has a tool to examine the certs here https://crt.sh/

Comment: The thumbprint of the root cert is 2b8f1b57330dbba2d07a6c51f70ee90ddab9ad8e however according to the tool there's no OCSP URL and the CRL status says "not revoked"   The thumbprint of the intermediate cert is 33e4e80807204c2b6182a3a14b591acd25b5f0db and the OCSP URL does exist and it's good.   I will try running this test ON the server console on a web browser and followup but it would be extremely pointless to block outbound traffic from a mailserver built to deliver mail to systems on the Internet, and I certainly have not intentionally set up the firewall to do that.

Comment: The intermediate cert (thumbprint listed above) has an OCSP URL of http://ocsp.usertrust.com and that resolves as an IPv6 IP address that is not reachable from the server (no IPv6 numbers are reachable from the server)   It has a CRL URL of http://crl.usertrust.com/USERTrustRSACertificationAuthority.crl and that also only resolves as an IPv6 address.   Do you think that this might be the problem?  That the only way this will work is if the mailserver has IPv6 connectivity to the Internet?

Comment: Oh for F*** sake!!!  Just scratch my comment!!   I will correct myself - this mailserver _IS_ supposed to be able to reach IPv6 hosts on the Internet - because I set it up that way a couple years ago!   The problem was simply that for whatever stupid reason IPv6 routing had failed on the Internet line coming in.  I rebooted the ISP-owned router, and after the router came back up online I was able to "ping -6 www.microsoft.com" and when I went into the Exchange management console and volia - now the certificate shows valid!!!!

Comment: So, the takeaway here is - Namecheap.com certificates and in fact ANY inexpensive certificates that are signed by Sectigo DO NOT USE any CRL or OCSP servers that are reachable by IPv4 ---AT ALL---   So that is a warning for people who setup networks that block IPv6.  It also begs the question - what is the point of a CRL if the CA's can revoke a certificate and a significant majority of the browsers on the internet CANNOT REACH THE CRL or OCSP servers?  And if a CRL is pointless what is to stop someone who has stolen a cert or private key from launching a MiM attack even if the cert is revoked

Comment: I congratulate you on solving the issue, but I think you are missing the point here. Of course those URLs resolve to IPv4 addresses. I can look up online right now that they do. What matters is if your server ASKS for an IPv4 address or an IPv6 address. As you stated, your IPv6 was messed up. There is nothing to say that IPv4 wouldn't be requested on an IPv4 only network. This, or you have your IPv6 / network settings configured improperly on your network. An IPv4 client will ask for an IPv4 address.

Comment: I stand corrected BUT your explanation isn't exactly right either.  IPv4 addresses are always A records IPv6 addresses are always AAAA records.  An IPv4 client can lookup EITHER record as can an IPv6 client.  You are correct that ocsp.usertrust.com has both records.  And in fact right now I can ping either of them from the server.  BUT, the problem appears to be that the server, or exchange, isn't falling back to using the IPv4 record IF the IPv6 host isn't reachable.  The failure here was upstream.  It COULD have been even further up the chain at the ISP where I couldn't have fixed it.

Comment: Also, by default Server 2012R2 and 2016 and 2019 setup both IPv6 and IPv4.  In an IPv4-only network, the default gateway is normally NOT advertising itself as an IPv6-aware router so there is no IPv6 default router to the Internet - HOWEVER - ALL OTHER SERVICES on the Exchange server WERE behaving by failing over. Some email servers (like google's) are fully IPv6 - and mail from my server WAS reaching them.  So the server's SMTP sender was trying IPv6 - failing - then reverting to IPv4.  It just doesn't appear to do this when checking certificate revocation lists.